# Saving draggable Elements That Push Others Out Of Way

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Using online resources I have been able to create a stack of draggable Elements That Push Others Out Of Way. Here is an example:

[jQuery Sortable with transitions and varying height support](https://codepen.io/Snarkie3/pen/XmvRQM)

Now I want to have a javascript array which keeps the status of the stack at any point of time. for example if the stack is in below status, the array will be something like this:

`myarray = [["Slide 2"],["Slide 1"],["Slide 4"],["Slide 3"]]`

[image]

What change should I make in my javascript code to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you have to set a empty array out of the loop.

You can use each() to loop on all li tags and use push function to add your element to your array then prop() function to get content of the class and then use native javascript split() functions to explode the the class with the delimiter ' '.

All you elements are now in the var tabSlides.

```js
$(".slides").sortable({
     placeholder: 'slide-placeholder',
    axis: "y",
    revert: 150,
    start: function(e, ui){
        
        placeholderHeight = ui.item.outerHeight();
        ui.placeholder.height(placeholderHeight + 15);
        $('<div class="slide-placeholder-animator" data-height="' + placeholderHeight + '"></div>').insertAfter(ui.placeholder);
    
    },
    change: function(event, ui) {
        
        ui.placeholder.stop().height(0).animate({
            height: ui.item.outerHeight() + 15
        }, 300);
        
        placeholderAnimatorHeight = parseInt($(".slide-placeholder-animator").attr("data-height"));
        
        $(".slide-placeholder-animator").stop().height(placeholderAnimatorHeight + 15).animate({
            height: 0
        }, 300, function() {
            $(this).remove();
            placeholderHeight = ui.item.outerHeight();
            $('<div class="slide-placeholder-animator" data-height="' + placeholderHeight + '"></div>').insertAfter(ui.placeholder);
        });
        
    },
    stop: function(e, ui) {
        $(".slide-placeholder-animator").remove();
        
        console.clear();
        var tabSlides = [];
        $('.slides li').each(function() {
          tabSlides.push($(this).prop('class').split(' ')[1]);
        });

        $.each(tabSlides, function(index, value){
          console.log(`${value}`);
        });
    },
});
```

```css
body {
    padding: 20px;
}
.slides {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 300px;
}
.slide {
    padding: 15px;
    background-color: #2F2F2F;
    margin: 0 0 15px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #FFF;
    border: 2px solid #444;
}

.slide-placeholder {
    background: #DADADA;
    position: relative;
}
.slide-placeholder:after {
    content: " ";
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 15px;
    background-color: #FFF;
}

.slide2 {
    height: 30px;
}
.slide3 {
    height: 50px;
}
.slide4 {
    height: 90px;
}
.slide5 {
    height: 35px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<p>Look! The items are different heights but the transitions still work</p>
<ul class="slides">
  <li class="slide slide2">Slide 2</li>
  <li class="slide slide1">Slide 1</li>
  <li class="slide slide4">Slide 4</li>
  <li class="slide slide3">Slide 3</li>
  <li class="slide slide5">Slide 5</li>
</ul>

<div class="result"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

this is the main logic of javascript array.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
   
    var arrayVariable = ['slide 1','slide 2','slide 3','slide 4','slide 5'],
        arrayLength = arrayVariable.length;
    var html="";
    for (i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
     var list =  '<li class="slide">'+arrayVariable[i]+'</li>'
     html += list;
     
    }
    $('.slides').html(html);

});
```

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
   
    var arrayVariable = ['slide 1','slide 2','slide 3','slide 4','slide 5'],
        arrayLength = arrayVariable.length;
    var html="";
    for (i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
     var list =  '<li class="slide">'+arrayVariable[i]+'</li>'
     html += list;
     
    }
    $('.slides').html(html);

});

    $(".slides").sortable({
     placeholder: 'slide-placeholder',
    axis: "y",
    revert: 150,
    start: function(e, ui){
        
        placeholderHeight = ui.item.outerHeight();
        ui.placeholder.height(placeholderHeight + 15);
        $('<div class="slide-placeholder-animator" data-height="' + placeholderHeight + '"></div>').insertAfter(ui.placeholder);
    
    },
    change: function(event, ui) {
        
        ui.placeholder.stop().height(0).animate({
            height: ui.item.outerHeight() + 15
        }, 300);
        
        placeholderAnimatorHeight = parseInt($(".slide-placeholder-animator").attr("data-height"));
        
        $(".slide-placeholder-animator").stop().height(placeholderAnimatorHeight + 15).animate({
            height: 0
        }, 300, function() {
            $(this).remove();
            placeholderHeight = ui.item.outerHeight();
            $('<div class="slide-placeholder-animator" data-height="' + placeholderHeight + '"></div>').insertAfter(ui.placeholder);
        });
        
    },
    stop: function(e, ui) {
        
        $(".slide-placeholder-animator").remove();
        
    },
});
```

```css
body {
    padding: 20px;
}
.slides {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 300px;
}
.slide {
    padding: 15px;
    background-color: #2F2F2F;
    margin: 0 0 15px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #FFF;
    border: 2px solid #444;
}

.slide-placeholder {
    background: #DADADA;
    position: relative;
}
.slide-placeholder:after {
    content: " ";
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 15px;
    background-color: #FFF;
}

.slide2 {
    height: 30px;
}
.slide3 {
    height: 50px;
}
.slide4 {
    height: 90px;
}
.slide5 {
    height: 35px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<ul class="slides">
    
</ul>
```